# Not able to specify target for JMS queue and probably therefore getting

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I am creating a WL JMS queue but while creating I don't see a target to attach this queue with (see below screen shot), so I create it without any target.

[image]

Now, after that when I try to connect using a JMS client code then I got below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'dq1'. Resolved '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Una
ble to resolve 'dq1'. Resolved '']; remaining name 'dq1'
        at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:251)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:466)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:274)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_12120_WLStub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:440)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

I am quite sure that my client code is not faulty because someone else could use same code and push message to the queue.

Is exception occuring because queue is not attached to any target? How can I attach this queue to target, like managed server?

I am having the JMS server targetted to the managed sever, I thought I would get a option to select target for queue as well but it is not coming and probably that's why exception. Please note that I have already tried creating sub-deployment template for queue but it didn't work.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

---

**Update:**

Issue is now isolated to managed servers, I could push messages to a queue which is targetted at admin server but when I tried same with managed server then it didn't succeed, below is what I did.

I have a managed server (running using node manager) - `ms1`, then I created a JMS server `JMSServer2` which is targeted at `ms1`

[image]

Then I created a JMS module `JmsModule2` whose target is `ms1`, created a JMS subdeployment `Subdeployment2` whose target is `JMSServer2` and created a connection factory and queue whose sub deployment is `Subdeployment2` and target as `JMSServer2`. Below screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must create a JMS server, which will be your target

Comment: Check this link  : http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/08-JMS--4468/jms.htm

Comment: I have already created a JMS server and JMS module, and then adding JMS resources (connection factory, queue etc.) in the JMS module, but somehow I am not getting it, and I have already tried sub deployment as well but with that too it isn't working.

Comment: which version of weblogic?

Comment: @Rouliboy WLS 12.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. Actually, it seems that you MUST create a subdeployment to enable targetting on JMS Queue.

I assume that you have properly created a **JMS Server** and **JMS Module**.

Now you must :

### Create a sub deployment

First you need to create a subdeployment specifying your JMS Server as a Target of this subdeployment :

[image]

Here my JMS Server is named `JMSServer`

### Create a queue with subdeployment

Then you create the JMS Queue. Notice that if you do not specify any subdeployment in Queue configuration, you can't see any target :

[image]

However if you properly specify the previously created subdeployment, you will see you target JMSServer :

[image]

And that's all!

Hope this helps.

## EDIT

I tested also on a cluster and it works fine when targetting a single managed server instance. You must

1. Create a JMS Server **specifying your single managed server instance as a Target.**
2. Create a JMS Module **specifying your single managed server instance as a Target using 'Part of the cluster' part.**
3. In this JMS module, create a subdeployment **specifying your single managed server instance as a Target using 'Part of the cluster' part.**
4. Finally create your JMS Queue and specify the corresponding subdeployment : you will see the JMS Server as a Target.

Comment: Thank you for your always valuable response. As such I had already tried this, let me try today from a fresh end.

Comment: BTW when you answered my last question about WL dependencies issue then you also created a POC, so at that time you created a physical queue in WL? If so then did you create the sub-deployment at that time as well?

Comment: I created the subdeployment yesterday, on a fresh install of WLS 12.1.3. Maybe you have forgotten to specify the target in the subdeployment creation?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did specify that as well, only thing is that I was working with managed server till now, now I will try with admin sever and if it works then I will try to understand why it didn't work with managed server because it should work with managed server as well.

Comment: Ok. I will test it tomorrow on cluster as my answer is about a single weblogic server (one instance). I will update my answer if needed.

Comment: Ok thanks. I could isolate the issue and it seems to be only when I try to use a JMS queue targetted at a managed server, I have updated my question with those details, I used a subdeployment plan as suggested by you but it didn't work. If you are trying then please try with just managed server, not with managed server in a cluster.

Comment: @pjj : I updated my answer. I tested on a single managed instance and it works fine.

Comment: I did everything apart from creating a cluster, is it the difference?

Comment: I don't understand. You have an Admin Server, a managed server instance and no cluster?

Comment: Yes, I have an admin server and one managed server, no cluster.

Comment: I tested with one Admin Server, a single managed server and no cluster. I followed what I describe on my answer (creating a JMS Server, JMS Module, JMS subdeployment, three with ms1 as target) and I can see my JMS Server in target of Queue. You must be missing one step.